# How to write a dynamic columns PIVOT query with multiple records?

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, pivot, pivot-table

EDIT2: I made a new usable example, reached the next step, but still have no clue on how to do some stuff. Check, please.

I have the table below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] (
             [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
            ,[Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL
            ,[Quantity] [int] NULL
            ,[Period] [nvarchar](10) NULL
            )

INSERT [dbo].[MyTable] VALUES
      ('foo', 1, 'Jan'),
      ('bar', 2, 'Jan'),
      ('foo', 1, 'Jan'),
      ('kin', 1, 'Jan'),
      ('blat', 5, 'Jan'),
      ('foo', 3, 'Feb'),
      ('bar', 1, 'Feb'),
      ('kin', 2, 'Feb'),
      ('blat',4, 'Feb'),
      ('foo', 1, 'Feb'),
      ('kin', 7, 'Feb'),
      ('blat', 1, 'Feb'),
      ('foo', 3, 'Mar'),
      ('bar', 1, 'Mar'),
      ('kin', 1, 'Mar'),
      ('blat', 1, 'Mar'),
      ('bar', 1, 'Mar'),
      ('kin', 2, 'Mar'),
      ('blat', 3, 'Mar')
```

And I want to achieve the result in the pic by using a PIVOT in a query:

[image]

My query so far:

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @columns = N'';
SELECT @columns += N', p.' + QUOTENAME(Period)
  FROM (SELECT Period FROM dbo.MyTable AS p
  GROUP BY Period) AS x;
SET @sql = N'
SELECT ' + STUFF(@columns, 1, 2, '') + '
FROM
(
  SELECT Name, Period, Quantity
   FROM dbo.MyTable AS p
) AS j
PIVOT
(
  SUM(Quantity) FOR Period IN ('
  + STUFF(REPLACE(@columns, ', p.[', ',['), 1, 1, '')
  + ')
) AS p;';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Gives me the result below:

[image]

How can I add row names (foo, bar, kin, blat), the column name Name, the SUMs etc.?

EDIT3: How to 'ORDER BY' the columns and the records?

Comment: Some actual sample data and expected results here would be helpful.

Comment: Why write a query? If you want it in excel, use a pivot table. This is the simplest solution. In fact I'm confused - you are already using a pivot table in your example

Comment: The sample data is in the pics and the expected result is in the 1st one.
Because it's a part of a whole process that needs to be automatised via SQL. Please, compare the result in excel with the one in SQL.

Comment: That picture isn't sample data, that's expected results; and pictures aren't helpful for consumable data.

Comment: I see, but why would you need sample data. My goal is to add the PartName rows in the query as they are in Excel, instead I have a SUM of PartName rows.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I made an edit. Don't know what else to do. I just need to know how to make a pivot in sql that has columns (no of which can dynamically change) rows and values.

Comment: If you want a _dynamic pivot in T-SQL_, your best bet is to google it. This has been done many times. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: I linked your tutorial in my question. the result in the tutorial is a single row, but I need multiple rows, so this is what I'm unable to achieve.

Comment: Oh we got the same article! Apologies for not reading your question properly. TBH I would just fiddle like you until I got it right. It would make it easier for everyone if you could post table creation and some inserts as an example - as per the comment by @Larnu

Comment: @Larnu: I changed it totally, please check. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good day Tomo,

Now that we have the queries to create the table and insert the data, it is simple and fast to help you :-)

Please check if the bellow solution fit your needs

```
select [Name],[Jan],[Feb],[Mar],[Jan]+[Feb]+[Mar] AS Grand_Total
from (
    SELECT [Name], [Quantity],[Period]
    FROM [MyTable]
) src
pivot
(
  SUM(Quantity)
  for Period in ([Jan],[Feb],[Mar])
) piv
GO
```

Next step is to convert this into dynamic PIVOT which is very simple once we have the static solution, if you need dynamic PIVOT.But first confirm the static PIVOT returns what you need and that you actually need a dynamic solution (maybe this fit your needs as it is)

Update: add "Grand Total" at the bottom using ROLLUP

```
;With MyCTE as(
select [Name],[Jan],[Feb],[Mar],[Jan]+[Feb]+[Mar] AS Grand_Total
from (
    SELECT [Name], [Quantity],[Period]
    FROM [MyTable]
) src
pivot
(
  SUM(Quantity)
  for Period in ([Jan],[Feb],[Mar])
) piv
)
select ISNULL([Name],'Totoal') as Name ,SUM([Jan]) [Jan],SUM([Feb]) [Feb],SUM([Mar]) [Mar],SUM([Grand_Total]) [Grand_Total]
from MyCTE
GROUP BY ROLLUP ([Name])
GO
```

Adding Dynamic Pivot version as the OP asked for

```
DECLARE 
    @ColumnsList1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @ColumnsList2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @ColumnsList3 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @ColumnsList1 = STUFF(
    (SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME([Period]) FROM [MyTable] FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
PRINT @ColumnsList1
SET @ColumnsList2 = REPLACE (@ColumnsList1, ',','+')
PRINT @ColumnsList2
SET @ColumnsList3 = (
    SELECT distinct ',SUM(' + QUOTENAME([Period]) + ') as ' + QUOTENAME([Period])
    FROM [MyTable] FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
PRINT @ColumnsList3

SET @query = '
;With MyCTE as(
select [Name],'+@ColumnsList1+','+@ColumnsList2+' AS Grand_Total
from (
    SELECT [Name], [Quantity],[Period]
    FROM [MyTable]
) src
pivot
(
  SUM(Quantity)
  for Period in ('+@ColumnsList1+')
) piv
)
select ISNULL([Name],''Totoal'') as Name '+@ColumnsList3+',SUM([Grand_Total]) [Grand_Total]
from MyCTE
GROUP BY ROLLUP ([Name])
'
execute(@query)
GO
```

Comment: I confirm it does the job. I can live without the Grand Total at the bottom.

Comment: I did not noticed that you asked for the Grand Total at the bottom `:-)`. I will add it after I will come back from the dinner, but I do want to say that all your requirement make no sense what so ever.You should do it in the client side and not in the server side. What is the sense in passing more data from the server to client?!? If you use a remote server then it means that you pass the data by internet... this will slowdown the entire procedure and will lead to more resources in the server side which will need to wait for the connection with the client

Comment: Done `:-)` You can check and mark it as answer if this fit your need (but I recommend to read my previous comment)

Comment: Works. Now for the dynamic PIVOT, please.

Comment: The excel pivot is part of a several hours process that is done in excel. My boss wants it to be automatised in SQL in order to shorten the time. This doesn't necessarily means that I don't agree with you.

Comment: Bosses are for administrative decision and professionals like DBA are these who should get the professional decisions. It is up to you to tell your boss when he is wrong or you do not do your job well (at least in my opinion)... Only after your boss gets all the facts he can choose the right decision

Comment: @Tomo , Don't you think that it is time to close the thread?!?